# Storing strings in an array

Tags: regex, perl

I am currently storing below lines in a file named `google.txt`. I want to seperate these lines and store those seperated strings in arrays.

Like for first line

```
@qf_file= q33AgCEv006441  
@date =    Tue Apr  3 16:12
@junk_message = User unknown
@rf_number = ngandotra@nkn.in

the line ends at the @rf_number at last emailadress
```

```
   q33AgCEv006441     1038 Tue Apr  3 16:12 <test10-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (User unknown)
                     <ngandotra@nkn.in>
    q33BDrP9007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <karuvoolam-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (Deferred: 451 4.2.1 mailbox temporarily disabled: paond.tndt)
                      <paond.tndta@nic.in>
    q33BDrPB007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <karuvoolam-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (User unknown)
                     paocorp.tndta@nic.in>
                                             <dtocbe@tn.nic.in>
                                             <dtodgl@nic.in>
    q33BDrPA007220    50153 Tue Apr  3 16:43 <karuvoolam-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (User unknown)
                     <dtokar@nic.in>
                     <dtocbe@nic.in>
    q2VDWKkY010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:37 <dhc-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (host map: lookup (now-india.net.in): deferred)
                     <arjunpan@now-india.net.in>
    q2VDWKkR010407  2221878 Sat Mar 31 19:31 <dhc-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (host map: lookup (aaplawoffices.in): deferred)
                      <amit.bhagat@aaplawoffices.in>
    q2U8qZM7026999   360205 Fri Mar 30 14:38 <dhc-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (host map: lookup (now-india.net.in): deferred)
                      <arjunpan@now-india.net.in>
                       <amit.bhagat@aaplawoffices.in>
    q2TEWWE4013920  2175270 Thu Mar 29 20:30 <dhc-list-bounces@lsmgr.nic.in>
                     (host map: lookup (now-india.net.in): deferred)
                               <arjunpan@now-india.net.in>
                               <amit.bhagat@aaplawoffices.in>
```

Comment: Do you have any code written? It's Stack Overflow etiquette to start some code and/or show what you have tried.

Comment: Also, could you clarify where the actual line endings are? You say the "first line", but reference the first 3 apparent lines in the code block...

Comment: If there are multiple emails, which one goes in `@rf_number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Untested*** Perl script:

Let's call this script `parser.pl`:

```
$file = shift;
open(IN, "<$file") or die "Cannot open file: $file for reading ($!)\n";
while(<IN>) {
    push(@qf_file, /^\w+/g); 
    push(@date, /(?:Sat|Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri)[\w\s:]+/g);
    push(@junk_message, /(?<=\().+(?=\)\s*<)/g);
    push(@rf_number, /(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>\s*$)/g);
}
close(IN);
```

This assumes the last email on the line should be the "rf_number" for that line. Note that emails may be tricky to print, as they have an `@` character, and perl is more than happy to print a non-existent list for you :-)

To call this in a command line:

```
parser.pl google.txt
```

**See this working [here](http://codepad.org/KmFD6Cp1).**

Comment: Thanks Kevlar for working on it really appreciate it ill look into the script right now

Comment: If you haven't tested it for your needs, don't accept the answer... You probably should just +1 it if you feel like its helped before accepting it.